# What's the most cost-effective way to improve stats?

Tags: scott-pilgrim-vs-the-world

[Scott Pilgrim vs. the World: The Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Pilgrim_vs._the_World:_The_Game) has quite a few stores where you can buy items that improve your stats (strength, defense, etc.), including hidden stores which have really expensive items.

Is it worth saving up the money for the expensive items?  What's the most economical way to max out my character stats?

Comment: ...[scott-pilgrim-vs-the-world] is 26 characters? ARGH! Why is it always ending at exactly 26 characters? Why are we spited so by our limit? Just being too long would be fine, but the volume of these 26-length names is driving me insane.

Comment: @Grace Note: My thoughts exactly.  :-/

Comment: why not [scott-pilgrim-v-the-world]?

Comment: @Alex Larzelere: Alas, that is 25 characters when the limit is 24.

Comment: dang, for some reason I thought it was 25

Answer (score 5, accepted):

via [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/961765-scott-pilgrim-vs-the-world/faqs/60744):

> The cheapest way to max your stats outside of No Account Video and the Techno Shack.
>
> World 1
>
> - Sushi Bar
>
>   - Avocado Hosomaki at $2.50 x 4 = $10.00 (+4 Spd)
> - Shock Wave Record
>
>   - Smashing Turnips at $16.95 x 12 = $203.40 (+96 Str)
>   - Crash and the Boys at $14.95 x 12 = $179.40 (+96 Spd)
>
> World 5
>
> - Scott's Dad BBQ
>
>   - Kebab at $4.95 x 2 = $9.90 (+4 Str)
>
> World 6
>
> - Mobile's Secret House
>
>   - Sauteed Shiitake at $9.95 x 25 = $248.75 (+100 Def and +100 WP)
>
> Total: $661.45

Answer (score -1):

heheh. the TRUE way to max you lv the fastest and cheapest way is on the first lv theres a shop where you can buy gum; to go, buy it. then go outside the shop and pause the game. while paused, press up up down down left right left right circle x while holding l2 and r2 down while doing all that. it must beimput fast. this kills you and grants $50. or at least, it NORMALLY would kill you, but the gum acts as a cosushin. so if you repeat this multipe times for about 15 min you should get $600 to buy stuff in the scotts late fees shop to max your lives count to 9, buy the stuff in there to up your stats all to max and your lv to max, and power through the game....unless you on supreme master, in which case don't let the power go to your head. I did this after i unlocked nega scott cuz i got tired of hard grinding.